# Getting "shared Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error" no metter what, after i moved to a different server

Tags: runtime, shared

I'm not a new User... but i lost my Login Info.
Don't know why it's says that i'm new here. Maybe a new section.
ANYWAY...

I have **moved** My Site to a new Shered windows Server.
and i getting this Error with any **aspx** file.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please See Example: http://picit.co.il/test.aspx

*It was working perfectly in the old server.*

This is my **Web.config** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="SiteAddress" value="http://www.picit.co.il/" />
    <add key="EMAIL_HOST" value="mail.barak.net.il"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_CONTACT_NAME" value="PicIt"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_USER" value="bonsite-barak.net.il"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_PASS" value="013013"/>
    <add key="MASTER_USERNAME" value="picit"/>
    <add key="MASTER_PASSWORD" value="2hH4HeC3"/>

    <add key="FCKeditor:UserFilesPath" value="~/Up/Main/"/>
    <add key="FCKeditor:BasePath" value="~/Controls/FCKeditor/"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Con" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=picitDB;user=User;password=Password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <globalization culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="22000"
minFreeThreads="16"
executionTimeout="500"
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
appRequestQueueLimit="1000" />
    <pages theme="Front">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="Website"/>
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI" tagPrefix="asp"/>
            <add tagPrefix="Upload" namespace="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" assembly="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"/>
            <add tagPrefix="fck" namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2"/>
            <add tagPrefix="swf" tagName="movie" src="~/Controls/swf.ascx"/>
            <add tagPrefix="Btn" tagName="Friend" src="~/Controls/btn_friend.ascx"/>
            <add assembly="Bound" namespace="CustomControls" tagPrefix="asp"/>
            <add assembly="skmValidators" namespace="skmValidators" tagPrefix="Vld"/>

            <add tagPrefix="CC" tagName="Upload" src="~/Controls/upload.ascx"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"     type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions,     Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd"     type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions,     Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd"     type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UploadHttpModule"     type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"     preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,     System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET" path="ScriptResource.axd"     verb="GET" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler"     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd"     verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions,         Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*"     type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions,     Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server event log? Any runtime error should be logged there as well, post here the real error message if you can..

Comment: All I have is an access to the FTP and the MySQL DB site. Is there any other way to do something?

Comment: No, you'll have to ask your host to either disable custom errors or send you the real errors from the web server event log.

Comment: ok. I will do it and will update soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of testing...
i found that there are a few lines that block the real Error..
WHY? I don't know.. But it's work for me..

I found that this lines are blocking the real error and showing the CustomError always.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Con" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial     Catalog=PicIt;user=small_site;password=small_site123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And this  Tag make the trouble too..

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

now i have differnt errors :) But! It's better then just non reletive error!
Thanks all for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the custom error mode to "Off" to view the error. After rectifying it and before deployment, change it to "On" and specify a default error page, as follows:-

```
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On">

    </customErrors>
```

such that your users will not be able to see the actual error and get your friendly error page where you can politely say "An error has occured! Sorry for the inconvenience ..." .

If the above solution is not working (i.e. even after setting the custom error mode to On, the same "Server Error" occurs, then the likely chance is that your web.config file is not well formed and has invalid characters etc.,

To resolve, it copy paste the contents of the file to a notepad, save it as an xml file and try to browse the xml file in the browser. If the xml file is unable to be rendered by the browser and throws error, then you can find the place where the tags are not well formed or invalid character(s) exist and rectify them.

Things worth noting is Web.config is case sensitive and even trailing / leading spaces can cause the above error.